# docker share files from the container to the host (not the other way)

Tags: docker, volume

I have ubuntu container with files inside, I wont to expose those files with the host container.

I have /deployment folder inside the container and I want to see it in the host:

When I run:

```
docker run --rm --name deployment  -v /dev/test:/deployment -it  deployment
```

the files doesn't exist anywhere (not in the container and not in the host)

When I run:

```
docker run --rm --name deployment -it  deployment
```

the files exists only in the container.

How can I see the container's files in the host

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can. Bind mounts are always from the host, into the container.

Comment: You could bind-mount a different directory in the container, then after starting the container you can create a soft link to the files you want to share. Or you can make sure the container creates/copies the files into the bind-mounted directory after it's started. Or you could leave the responsibility to the person starting the image to make sure they bind-mount the right files into the container. I would say it depends a bit on your use-case.

Comment: If directly accessing the files is important, also consider running the process directly on the host, without Docker.